# Pythonista, loaded images are completely blue

Tags: python, user-interface, pythonista

I am trying to load images from an url into a button, but they all appear blue.

```
def load_jpeg_image(image_url):
    # Fetch image data from the URL
    image_data = requests.get(image_url).content

    try:
        # Create a PIL Image from the JPEG data
        pil_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))

        # Convert to RGB color space
        pil_image_rgb = pil_image.convert('RGB')

        # Save the RGB image to a BytesIO object
        rgb_image_data = io.BytesIO()
        pil_image_rgb.save(rgb_image_data, format='JPEG')
        rgb_image_data = rgb_image_data.getvalue()

        # Create a UI Image from the RGB data
        ui_image = ui.Image.from_data(rgb_image_data)
        
        return ui_image



# Create a view
view = ui.View()
view.background_color = 'white'  # Set the background color to white

# Set up variables for layout
margin = 10
image_width = (view.width - 4 * margin) / 3
image_height = image_width

for i, image_url in enumerate( image_urls):

    # Create a button with the image
    image_button = ui.Button(frame=(margin + i % 3 * (image_width + margin), margin + i // 3 * (image_height + margin), image_width, image_height))
    image_button.name = str(i)
    image_button.image = load_jpeg_image(image_url)
    image_button.action = image_tapped
    view.add_subview(image_button)
```

When looking at the link the images are there and not blue.
I try to load jpg.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete reproducible executable example

Comment: you have `try` without `except`. Better create `minimal working code` - so we could simply copy and test it. You could also show your images. Maybe problem is in images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pythonista, images in buttons are used by default as "templates", to be filled with the button tint color.

To use the actual image, you need to change the image rendering mode, as in this example:

```
import ui

view = ui.View()

image_as_template = ui.Image("test:Pythonista")
image_as_original = image_as_template.with_rendering_mode(ui.RENDERING_MODE_ORIGINAL)

button = ui.Button(image=image_as_original)

view.add_subview(button)
view.present()
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you :)